# How do I count varchar in a varchar using TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, textmatching

What is the best way to count the occurence of a varchar within a varchar.

I rather not loop through a text in order to find certain combinations.

This select only find the first

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('!','HOW MANY TIMES IS ! IN THIS TEXT ? THIS IS MY QUESTION !' ) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Returns 1

I need a method to find the total number of matches

```
TABLE DATA
SEARCHTEXT     LONGTEXT
!              HOW MANY TIMES IS ! IN THIS TEXT ? THIS IS MY QUESTION !
HELLO          HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO
L              HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO
e              more testdata
```

Expected result

```
Count SEARCHTEXT  LONGTEST
2     !           MANY TIMES IS ! IN THIS TEXT ? THIS IS MY QUESTION !
6     HELLO       HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO
12    L           HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO
2     e           more testdata
```

Using mssql server 2005

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `replace` to make each occurrence 1 character longer, and count the number of added characters:

```
select  len(replace(txt, search, search + '#')) - len(txt) as Count
,       *
from    YourTable
```

[Full example at SE Data.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/105217/)