# Count the occurrences of substring

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a html string:

```
<img src="aaa"/>blah blah <img src="333"/>long content
```

I just want to count the number of img tag occurrences in the string field. 
I know i can use CLR in SQL server or i could use something like HtmlAgilityPack to parse the string, but i have no permission to install CLR and want a more effective way.

So is there any way to use normal SQL to achieve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I count varchar in a varchar using TSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641765/how-do-i-count-varchar-in-a-varchar-using-tsql). There is a very good answer here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
Declare @string varchar(1000)
Set @string = '<img src="aaa"/>blah blah <img src="333"/>long content<img'
select len(@string) - len(replace(@string, '<img', 'xxx'))
```

Answer (score 1):

One dirty trick you can use is,

```
select (len(myCol) - len(replace(myCol, '<img ', ''))) / len('<img ') AS imgCount
from myTable
```

Comment: thanks but since geek gave the first answer, i gave him a credit.